# How to draw a histogram chart in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

As per My requirements i need to generate a histogram chart using cocoa framework and objective c.

If any one knows the solution please let me know ASAP.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). It doesn't support histograms directly, but if you calculate the bins and counts yourself, a bar plot is pretty easy to set up. The framework handles drawing everything including the axes and labels. It works on Mac, iPhone, and iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you can use a custom UIView subclass and perform the drawing by hand (overwrite drawRect:) or add UIViews for every bar (making nice animations possible with few code, but will not be efficient if many bars are needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own `CALayer` using **CoreAnimation**.

You will just need some basic `CALayers` with their colors, borders and shadows to draw the bars and some `CATextLayers` to draw the text on the axis or below bars.

With some basic **CA** knowledge it will be easy and allow you to easily customize the graph with animations or effects..

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old but i found a link that gives sample code for drawing histogram

http://www.keepedge.com/iphone_charts/histogram_chart.html

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/). It does exactly what you want.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dsbarchart